# Check if a random variable is well-defined

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics, random-variables

At an oral examination the teacher asks questions to a student, one by one, until one of the following event occurs: the student gives 3 correct answers or the student gives 4 wrong answers. In the first case, the student is accepted to the written examination. Let p be the probability that a student answers correctly to any of the questions. Let X be the total number of questions asked until a decision (positive or negative). Write the random variable X and prove that it is correctly defined.

The approach I considered was to take the possible values of X and calculate their respective probabilities(use of geometric distribution). However, I have problems at proving that it is well-defined as the sum of the probabilities is not 1.
Can somebody help me?

Comment: Please see [this article on MathSE protocol](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33190/how-to-avoid-downvotes-for-beginners-questions/33236#33236).
As onerous as the article may appear to you, it provides a defense mechanism against the MathSE forum being used as a *do my homework* forum.  In particular, please see the **Edit-Tools** section of the article, and the portion of the article that discusses *showing work*.  Homework problems are allowed, as long as the protocol is
observed.

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  In order to see what mistakes you are making, we need to see your work.  This [Mathjax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.